# Chat Channel Definition and Registry

Tags: java, chat

This is an excerpt of a part of a (very large) program that I'm writing. This particular section handles the creation and management of chat channels.

However, I think that this code is rather complicated and not as clean/easy as it should be.

```
package com.lolfakename.chat;

import com.lolfakename.LocalUser;

import javax.persistence.EntityExistsException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Handle creation and management of Chat Channels, which can then be used to send messages to all users within that specific channel.
 */
public class ChatChannel {

    private static HashMap<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels = new HashMap<>(5, 0.8f); // ChannelID, ChatChannel Object
    /**
     * Register a new Chat Channel to be used by the system.
     * @param channel A ChatChannel ID to register
     */
    public static void registerChannel(ChatChannel channel) {
        if (!registeredChannels.containsKey(channel.getChannelId())) {
            registeredChannels.put(channel.getChannelId(), channel);
        } else {
            throw new EntityExistsException("A channel with ID " + channel.getChannelId() + " already exists! Can not register!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove a Channel from the server's registry.
     * Once a channel is removed from the server, it can no longer be used without risking a lot of issues. Only do this
     * when you're ready to dispose a channel.
     * @param channel
     */
    public static void deregisterChannel(ChatChannel channel) {
        registeredChannels.remove(channel.getChannelId());
    }

    /**
     * Get a ChatChannel instance by its ID.
     * @param id The ChatChannel ID to retrieve.
     * @return Returns the requested ChatChannel, or <code>null</code> if it doesn't exist.
     */
    public static ChatChannel getChannelById(String id) {
        return registeredChannels.getOrDefault(id, null);
    }

    /** The actual ChatChannel item is defined BELOW THIS LINE **/

    /**
     * The friendly name of the Chat Channel instance.
     */
    private String name;

    /**
     * The Short ID of the current Chat Channel.
     */
    private String id;

    /**
     * Preferences for the current ChatChannel, advanced feature.
     */
    private HashMap<String, Object> preferences;

    /**
     * A list of listening Players in the current Chat Channel.
     * People in {@link #allowedToSpeak} will inherit the ability to listen as well.
     */
    private List<LocalUser> members;

    /**
     * A list of Players in this channel that may speak.
     */
    private List<LocalUser> allowedToSpeak;

    /**
     * Create a new ChatChannel instance.
     * ChatChannels are groups of users that receive messages sent within the same ChatChannel. In order to actually
     * be able to send a message to a ChatChannel, its instance must be registered using {@link #registerChannel(ChatChannel)}.
     * @param name The long (friendly) name of the ChatChannel to be created.
     * @param id The short (usable) ID of the Chat Channel.
     * @param preferences A set of Preferences for a Chat Channel
     */
    public ChatChannel(String name, String id, HashMap<String, Object> preferences) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    public ChatChannel(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.preferences = new HashMap<>();
    }

    /**
     * Get the ID of the current ChatChannel instance.
     * @return Returns the String ID of the current ChatChannel.
     */
    public String getChannelId() { 
        return id; 
    }

    /**
     * Check if a player can talk in the given channel.
     * This check should be executed when the player switches their active channel, or when they attempt to quick-chat
     * to another channel.
     * @param user The user to check for chat capability
     * @return Returns TRUE if the user can speak in the channel.
     */
    public boolean canPlayerTalk(LocalUser user) {
        return (allowedToSpeak.contains(user));
    }

    /**
     * Add a new player to the Chat Channel.
     * @param player The LocalUser to add to the Chat Channel.
     * @param canSpeak Set to TRUE if the user should be allowed to speak, false otherwise.
     */
    public void addMember(LocalUser player, boolean canSpeak) {
        members.add(player);
        if (canSpeak) {
            allowedToSpeak.add(player);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove a player from the channel entirely.
     * @param player The LocalUser to remove from the channel.
     */
    public void removeMember(LocalUser player) {
        members.remove(player);
        allowedToSpeak.remove(player);
    }

    /**
     * Get a list of members that can hear messages in the channel.
     * @return Returns a List of all members of the current chat.
     */
    public List<LocalUser> getMembers() {
        return members;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a user's ability to speak in the current channel.
     * @param user The user to allow speech for.
     */
    public void allowSpeech(LocalUser user) {
        if (members.contains(user)) {
            allowedToSpeak.add(user);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This user is not in this channel!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove a user's ability to speak in the current channel.
     * @param user
     */
    public void denySpeech(LocalUser user) {
        if (members.contains(user)) {
            allowedToSpeak.remove(user);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This user is not in this channel!");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the specified Preference for the current chat.
     * Note that this method will return an Object. It is up to the calling method to parse it as it needs to be parsed.
     * @param key The preference key to look up.
     * @return Returns the Object assigned to that preference. Will return <code>null</code> if no value.
     */
    public Object getPreference(String key) {
        return preferences.getOrDefault(key, null);
    }

    /**
     * Set a preference for the current ChatChannel.
     * Note that this <i>will</i> overwrite any existing values, so be careful.
     * @param key The preference key to set.
     * @param value The value to set for this key.
     */
    public void setPreference(String key, Object value) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }

    /**
     * Get the actual Preferences object used by this ChatChannel.
     * @returns Returns a HashMap of the current Preference set for this chat.
     */
    public HashMap<String, Object> getPreferences() {
        return preferences;
    }

    /**
     * Set the Preferences in this ChatChannel to the HashMap specified. Will overwrite ALL preferences!
     * @param preferences The new Preferences to set.
     */
    public void setPreferences(HashMap<String, Object> preferences) {
        this.preferences = preferences;
    }
}
```

I've attempted to document the code as best I could, so it's hopefully (rather) self-explanatory. However, I'm still pretty sure that it has problems (hence my posting here).

The actual code to handle chat events is not actually written yet, but it's roughly similar to this:

```
Chat.sendMessageToUsers(ChatChannel.getChannelById(sender.getActiveChannelId()).getMembers(), "<" + sender.getName() + "> " + message);
```

Would there be any bugs or potential large-scale issues (both performance and general failure-to-work) that could spring up with how this code is currently arranged and set up? If so, how could I solve them?

(And, I'm not sure this is within the scope of this site, so if it's not, please correct me and I will remove this), but I'd like some way to have a "shortcut" for some default and heavily used channels (like, say `ChatChannel.GLOBAL` instead of `ChatChannel.getChannelById("global")`). If I could put this sort of thing in the code relatively easily, can someone advise on a way to implement this?

Comment: Your setters are wrong, as you're not setting anything in the first one, and should be merging two maps in the second. I'd also add methods to enable preference removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     private static HashMap<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels = new HashMap<>(5, 0.8f); // ChannelID, ChatChannel Object
> ```

This line would not need to wrap this display if the comment was before it rather than the on the same line.

```
    // map ChannelID to ChatChannel Objects
    private static Map<String, ChatChannel> registeredChannels = new HashMap<>(5, 0.8f);
```

I also changed from the implementation (`HashMap`) to the interface (`Map`).  This makes it easier to change implementations in the future.

That's even more true of `preferences`, which get passed around as a method parameter as well.

> ```
>         if (!registeredChannels.containsKey(channel.getChannelId())) {
>             registeredChannels.put(channel.getChannelId(), channel);
>         } else {
>             throw new EntityExistsException("A channel with ID " + channel.getChannelId() + " already exists! Can not register!");
>         }
> ```

I don't like using negative conditions with `else` clauses.

```
        if (registeredChannels.containsKey(channel.getChannelId())) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("A channel with ID " + channel.getChannelId() + " already exists! Can not register!");
        }

        registeredChannels.put(channel.getChannelId(), channel);
```

The simple thing is to just switch the order of the clauses.  Doing that in this case puts a `throw` in the first clause.  Since a `throw` ends processing of the method, we can get rid of the `else`.

> ```
>     public static ChatChannel getChannelById(String id) {
>         return registeredChannels.getOrDefault(id, null);
>     }
> ```

You can just say

```
    public static ChatChannel getChannelById(String id) {
        return registeredChannels.get(id);
    }
```

The default `return` of `get` is already `null`.

> ```
>     private List<LocalUser> members;
>     private List<LocalUser> allowedToSpeak;
> ```

Considering how you use these, they would make more sense as sets.

```
    private Set<LocalUser> members = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<LocalUser> allowedToSpeak = new HashSet<>();
```

Now testing membership is constant time, not linear.  That seems to be the main purpose of these fields.

I also initialized these which solves a bug in your current class where they never get initialized.